# I want to change the text size and icon of this screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This is a holo theme, I just want to change the android icon to an image that I will choose and the text size of the bar

[image]

Comment: set the android:icon attribute in your manifest.

Comment: And so far, you've tried...?

Comment: Yes.. work now.. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the app icon using editing manifest.xml

```
android:icon="@mipmap/your_image_name"  or
android:icon="@drawable/your_image_name"
```

first paste your image to res -> drawable or mipmap folder

but you can not change the size of title for that you have to create Toolbar